# Delete and update cascading doesn't affect on child table in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cascade

I've known of using 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON' or including an attribute in my SQLite connection string like this:

```
con = "Data source = myData.sdb; foreign keys = true";
```

I've also made a demo to test and it worked OK, however the demo was so simple with a Parent table having only 1 single primary key. Now I have to deal with a more complex case, and the cascading doesn't work at all. Here are my tables (Parent and child):

```
-- Parent table
create table ChuyenCongTac(
 MaNV varchar(12) references NhanVien(MaNV) on delete cascade on update cascade,
 NgayChuyenCT datetime,
 MaPhongTruoc int references PhongBan(MaPhong) on delete cascade on update cascade
 MaPhongSau int references PhongBan(MaPhong) on delete cascade on update cascade,
 NoiCongTacNgoai nvarchar(100),
 primary key (MaNV,NgayChuyenCT)
);

-- Child table
create table ChucVuChuyenCongTac(
 MaNV varchar(12) references ChuyenCongTac(MaNV) on delete cascade on update cascade,
 NgayChuyenCT datetime references ChuyenCongTac(NgayChuyenCT) on delete cascade on update cascade,
 CongTacTruoc bit,
 primary key(MaNV,NgayChuyenCT,MaChucVu,CongTacTruoc)
)
```

I think there is some problem with my cascading declarations, do you see anything wrong with them? The noticeable point here is the Parent table has a primary key of 2 columns (a double primary key). I'm not sure if it is OK. I hope this is of my fault in the creating table queries, not of SQLite. Last time, I was very happy after doing the cascading successfully in SQLite, it turned me on very much to use SQLite for my current project.

## UPDATE

I now know the problem of update and delete cascading, just re-designed the table. However it works only when in the SQLite query window in VS 2010 (with PRAGMA foreign_keys=on first). My C# code doesn't work, while I've done successfully in the demo project. Really stuck at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared two separate one-column foreign keys from the child to the parent.

To declare a multi-column foreign key, use syntax like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ChucVuChuyenCongTac(
    MaNV VARCHAR(12),
    NgayChuyenCT DATETIME,
    CongTacTruoc BIT,
    PRIMARY KEY(MaNV, NgayChuyenCT, MaChucVu, CongTacTruoc),
    FOREIGN KEY(MaNV, NgayChuyenCT)
        REFERENCES ChuyenCongTac(MaNV, NgayChuyenCT)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Thank you, as my Update said, this is also what I found in my problem before. However, now the query is OK only in SQLite Query window, in my C# code, it doesn't work. This is really not what I expected because I have also included "foreign keys = true" in my connection string and had made a demo project (about using auto cascading in SQLite) successfully before. Anyway, your answer would be accepted. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work"? Show the error message, or the differences between what you expected and what you got.

Comment: After re-creating the table following the correction above (for Child table), I tried executing some update commands on the Parent table in the Query window (right in VS 2010) and it worked (it didn't before). But I tried executing those same update commands on the Parent table in my C# code, the Child table is not updated accordingly. There is no error message, just no update cascaded to the child table. As I said, I already included "foreign keys=true" in my connection string, this problem is not related to Table design. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A little bit late, but I add this as a self-note and for those who stumble across the same problem.

Adding "foreign keys = true" to your connection string in your C# application won't activate foreign key support. Instead do something like this:

```
query.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;";
query.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will enable foreign key support for the current connection.